# Protractor find element by template reference variable (#)

Tags: angular, protractor

Is there any way to locate element by template reference variable name (#)?

`<input #someInput>`

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

These template references do not get rendered in the DOM so you will not be able to use them to identify your elements. They are only present in your Angular templates.

---

**Previous answer:**

Can you try just locating by css directly like so

```
element(by.css('#someInput'));
```

I manually tested this in the browser and it appeared to work as seen below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use protractor locator `cssContainingText`

```
Element(by.cssContainingText('input', 'variable name'));
```